# importing images into an existing Android Studio project

Tags: android, image, import, project

I have a problem with Android Studio: I use a template found on internet, and I can't import images in it.
Usually, it's ok to import images in my projects, but here, I have this error: http://hpics.li/fe183bb.

It is strange, because the images appear correctly in the res layout, but it crashes when I want to compile the application.

Do you know why, and how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The library you are using does not have a property named srcCompat.
Try to use the background property instead

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I use the background property, please ? (I've been using Android Studio for one week : I'm a beginner)

Comment: something like this
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

Comment: also as the name suggest background is background and src is a source that comes on top of the background